# Avoid temp file in call to suprocess.run()

Tags: python, subprocess

In a Python project, I need the output of an external (non-Python) command.
Let's call it `identify_stuff`.*

#### Command-line scenario

When called from command-line, this command requires a file name as an argument.
If its input is generated dynamically, we cannot pipe it into the command – this doesn't work:

```sh
cat input/* | ./identify_stuff > output.txt
cat input/* | ./identify_stuff - > output.txt
```

... it strictly requires a file name it can open, so one needs to create a temporary file on disk for the output of the first command, from where the second command can read the data.

However, the `identify_stuff` program really iterates over the input lines only once, no seeking or re-reading is involved.
So in Bash we can avoid the temporary file with the `<(...)` construct.
This works:

```sh
./identify_stuff <(cat input/*) > output.txt
```

This pipes the output of the first command to some device at a path `/dev/fdX`, which can be used for opening a stream like the path to a regular file on disk.

#### Actual scenario: call from within Python

Now, instead of just `cat input/*`, the input text is created inside a Python program, which continues to run after the output of `identify_stuff` has been captured.
The natural choice for calling an external command is the standard-library's `subprocess.run()`.

For performance reasons, I would like to avoid creating a file on-disk.
Is there any way to do this with the `subprocess` tools?
The `stdin` and `input` parameters of `subprocess.run` won't work, because the external command ignores STDIN and specifically requires a file-name argument.

---

*Actually, it's this tool: https://github.com/jakelever/Ab3P/blob/master/identify_abbr.C

Comment: Supply the input as stdin, and specify `/dev/stdin` as the filename?  I've never actually tried that, so not sure how well it will work.

Comment: Oh yes, that does indeed work. At least on Linux (just like the command-line scenario).